# (ios) How can I receive didReceiveLocalNotification out of delegate

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I m trying to get a UILocalNotification scheduled to launch or get foreground my application.
I know delegate function has didReceiveLocalNotification, but I would like to be aware of this notification in a view controller.

Anyone knows if it is possible to add an observer to these local notifications?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't post a notification yourself in `didReceiveLocalNotification` using `NSNotificationCenter`?
In your view controller then you can observe that user-defined notification.

Comment: Well, the fact is that I m developing just a static library that other ios applications can include itselves. Because of that I have no access to delegate class which should capture didReceiveLocalNotification and send through NSNotificationCenter a user-defined notification. Anyway thanks for the answer (Did not expect that speed on getting answers :)